# tensordot equivalent of numpy-einsum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum, tensordot

I am trying to figure out the `tensordot` equivalent of the following expression, as sparse package does not support einsum (the sparseness of the original problem is much better than the example below).

The place I am stuck with is the contraction ii->i, I don't know how to interpret this.

```
mki_shape=(25,25,121)
mki=np.random.uniform(size=mki_shape)
tik_shape=(10,121,25)
tik=np.random.uniform(size=tik_shape)

tim=np.einsum('mki,tik->tim',mki,tik)
print(tim.shape)
```

Comment: Do you desire to use just `np.tensordot()` or all other multiplicative functions such as `dot`, `matmul` or simply `*`?

Comment: I can use any, `dot`,`matmul`, and `*` but not `einsum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the result as with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) with a for loop, [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) and a [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) operation:

```py
mki_shape=(25,25,121)
mki=np.random.uniform(size=mki_shape)
tik_shape=(10,121,25)
tik=np.random.uniform(size=tik_shape)

tim=np.einsum('mki,tik->tim',mki,tik)
print(tim.shape)
(10, 121, 25)

tim2 = np.array([np.matmul(mki[:,:,i],tik[:,i,:].T) for i in range(mki_shape[2])])
tim2 = np.transpose(tim2,axes=(2,0,1))
print(tim2.shape)
(10, 121, 25)

np.allclose(tim,tim2)
True
```

All you need to know is the dimension which you want to reduce and take care that the dimensions for matmul line up (hence the transpose).